# Ignores html special characters when reading website using Java DocumentBuilder()

Tags: java, sax, android-xml

I am trying to read a website (HTML) using Java DocumentBuilder(), it is reading but when there is html `&pound;` `&ldquo;` sign or any other html especial characters. It stops reading anything after the special character instead it returns null. Many other people has asked similar questions. But there isn't any constructive answer for that. Please let me know if anyone knows the way to solve this problem. Please find my code here.

`<html>`
`<body>`
`<p>`it is being increased from £488 to £600 `</p>`
`<p>`Ronals says:  “Schools in this are falling under proverty“ `</p>`
`</body>`
`</html>`

In order to read these i wrote following code.

```
private String extractTheTitle(String responseBody) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    ByteArrayInputStream encXML = new  ByteArrayInputStream(responseBody.getBytes("UTF8"));
    Document embeddedDoc = builder.parse(encXML);
    NodeList titleNodes = embeddedDoc.getElementsByTagName("p");

    if (titleNodes != null && titleNodes.getLength() > 0) {
    for(int i = 0; i<titleNodes.getLength(); i++) {                 

            Element aTitleElement = (Element) titleNodes.item(i);
        aTitleElement.normalize();
        Node titleContent = aTitleElement.getFirstChild();
        String nodeText = titleContent.getNodeValue();
        myArrlist.add(i , "<p>"+nodeText+"</p>");
        }
    }

}
```

the above code does not output anything after the £ or “ I have tried many ways but nothing worked. Please let me know if anyone knows any answer. I took help from  following website. But that did not help. I don't want to remove the html special characters. Because i am reading these p tags and re-constructing my own html page just with those

tag.

http://www.developerfeed.com/xml/common/issues/xml-parsing-failing-due-encoding-not-being-utf-8

Comment: Have you tried URLEncoder and URLDecoder? [Java 6 API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/)

Comment: I tested your code just now and had no problem. Can you maybe explain more about how you get the responseBody as I suspect the issue could be there?

Comment: I am gettig the the response body with HttpGet request and then passing the response body to the function. Here is the code that i have used to get the responseBody. HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(pageURL);                                                   ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String responseBody = client.execute(getMethod, responseHandler);

Answer (score 1):

Every aTitleElement (`<p>...</p>`) contains more than one Node, one of which is an entity. So instead of getFirstChild on has to iterate over all children; normalize does not help there.

```
StringBuilder pText = new StringBuilder();
NodeList children = aTitleElement.getChildNodes();
for (int j = 0; j < children.getLength(); ++j) {
    Node child = children.item(j);
    if (child.getNodeType() == Node.ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE) {
        ...
    }
    pText.append(child.getNodeValue());
}
nodeText = pText.toString();
```

---

***Test file***

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Saluton,&pound;&ldquo; mondo!</p>
</body></html>
```

***My code***

```
    DocumentBuilder builder =
        DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document embeddedDoc = builder.parse(new File("/home/joop/test.html"));
    NodeList pNodes = embeddedDoc.getElementsByTagName("p");
    StringBuilder pText = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < pNodes.getLength(); ++i) {
        Element pElement = (Element) pNodes.item(i);
        NodeList children = pElement.getChildNodes();
        for (int j = 0; j < children.getLength(); ++j) {
            Node child = children.item(j);
            String value = child.getNodeValue();
            if (value == null) {
                System.out.println("node name=" + child.getNodeName()
                    + ": " + child.getNodeType());
            }
            pText.append(value);
        }
        pText.append("\n");
    }
    String text = pText.toString();
    System.out.println("FOUND TEXT:");
    System.out.println(text);
```

***Result***

```
FOUND TEXT:
Saluton,£“ mondo!
```

Comment: Hi Joop, thanks for your suggested code. It now reads the line after the especial characters such as "&pounds" or "&ld" or any other. But it does not read the "&pounds" instead it returs null for that especial character. Is there any way that i can read the special character and use it as it is without any modification to the characters or without returning null.

Comment: Do i need to create any methods to check the special characters?

Comment: If you get null you probably have sub tags like `<br>` or `<b>`. The HTML should contain an XHTML doctype like: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` and then even the correct character is filled in. My test on node type is not needed. (Reading the doctype takes long.)

Comment: Hi Joop, thanks for your reply. There isn't any <br> or <b> within the tags. As i said it only has html special characters within the "<p>...</p>" tags. I can't find a way to read these special characters "&pound &ldquo &rsquo". I really appreciate your help. Please let me know if you have any thoughts about it. If you need my code, i can send you the full codes for you to test. Please try to read any html files that contains special characters. You can see the problem. Here is the doctype of the html and there isn't any problem with that.

Comment: "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">"

Comment: I made test code; without doctype one gets null for the entity reference, with doctype, it reads the dtd from the internet (!) which _must_ be an XML DTD. As said my code works. I'll experiment a bit more.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide my code. If the error still remains, yes send your code and data to joop_eggen at the yahoo dot de.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It is still showing null. But good thing is that it now shows the html especial characters. Your examples works fine. But try this website, you will see the problem. http://www.towerhamlets.gov.uk/news__events/news/january/extra_cash_to_support_pupils_i.aspx?lang=en-gb     I am giving the code please find above. You can see what it returns.

Comment: I am impressed, the raw content is _not_ XHTML and misses `/>` a lot. So you've corrected that already. The `<p>` paragraphs still contain `<a>` and `<strong>`. One should recursively walk through their children collecting text for `child.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE`.

Answer (score 0):

Code that will extract the data. Please use the website url.

****NEw Code***

```
public void process() {
   HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet("URL OF THE WEB SITE GOES HERE");
   try {
   ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
   String websiteBody = client.execute(getMethod, responseHandler);
   String title = extractBody(websiteBody);
   }
}



private String extractBody(String responseBody) throws Exception {

DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document embeddedDoc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(responseBody)));
//ByteArrayInputStream encXML = new   ByteArrayInputStream(responseBody.getBytes("UTF8"));      
//Document embeddedDoc = builder.parse(encXML); 
//Document embeddedDoc = builder.parse(new File("/home/joop/test.html"));
    NodeList pNodes = embeddedDoc.getElementsByTagName("p");
    StringBuilder pText = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < pNodes.getLength(); ++i) {
        Element pElement = (Element) pNodes.item(i);
        NodeList children = pElement.getChildNodes();
        for (int j = 0; j < children.getLength(); ++j) {
            Node child = children.item(j);
            String value = child.getNodeValue();
            if (value == null) {
                System.out.println("node name=" + child.getNodeName()
                    + ": " + child.getNodeType());
                value = value+convert(child.getNodeName());

            }
            System.out.println(value.replaceAll("null", ""));
            pText.append(value);
        }
        pText.append("\n");
    }
    String text = pText.toString();
    System.out.println("FOUND TEXT:");
    System.out.println(text);
    }
```